# Word VBA detect blank pages after odd/even section break

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new here so be gentle... lol

I've made a document and have separated it into chapters (sections) and am numbering the pages of each section as follows

1-1 of 9
2-1 of 6
etc

I'm using odd page breaks to put the first page of my sections in my place of preference.  Of course using odd/even page breaks will under the right circumstances result in a non-printing blank page at the end of the section which of course is exactly what is supposed to happen.  The problem is that in those cases my page numbers end up as for example, 2-1 of 13 but 13 is a non printing blank page and so the last printing page is 2-12 of 13.  I've tried .goto to that page but apparently it won't allow you to .goto that page.  I pared down my code to just outputting the number of pages to a msgbox to prevent any ancillary nonsense from getting in the way of the point.  Here it is:

```
Dim i, x

Dim FooterPages As Integer

Dim Sect As Integer

With ActiveDocument

    For i = 1 To 10

        'Footer page numbers
        ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToSection, Count:=i + 2
        Sect = .ActiveWindow.Selection.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber)

        FooterPages = .Sections(Sect).Range.Information(3) - .Sections(Sect - 1).Range.Information(3)
        MsgBox FooterPages

    Next i

End With
```

I would really appreciate some help with a bit of code to detect that last page so I can subtract it from the total page count of that section.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear to me: Usually, we'd use field codes to generate this information. Are you, or are you not usignfield codes?

Comment: I am using field codes to generate the "1-1" it's only the " of 9" part that I'm adding.  That's what is being thrown off.

Comment: Ugh...ok I figured it out.  I added an "UPDATE" section below my question above.  Thanks all for taking the time to look and sorry to have wasted any time.